# Excel 2010, F2 edit mode, color of ranges in formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, colors

I use Excel 2010. Recently I watched an instructional video that was made using a more recent version of Excel and noticed a feature I liked.

While editing a cells formula using F2, the ranges involved in the formula were not only bound by a thin colored box, they were also translucently shaded in that color. This is so much better visually and would love to know if it is possible to get Excel 2010 to do this. Some option or plugin that I need.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Could it be that references in your formula are to cells in another sheet? Cell references and referenced cells within the same sheet are colored when editing.

Answer (score 0):

The colours in formulas is a built-in function. You cannot remove it or make it display differently.

Comment: Your answer sounds like the opposite of what was asked.  The question isn't how to remove or change that feature, it's how to reproduce it in older versions.

Comment: ok, could you propose another reply?
Still... it is requested to change from older version display (2010) to a newer version display (2013).
This cannot be changed.